# Rspec cannot find examples, when wrapped in PHP exec() call

Tags: php, ruby, rspec, webdriver

The goal here is to execute a ruby script (with rake.invoke), within a PHP 'exec' command.

I have a working rspec configuration, that executes cleanly (here is the headless rake task eg, but note that it works both headless and 'headed' for the below example)

```
FILE=./../tools/wr_audit_dom.rb WR_DEBUG=1 bundle exec rake local:headless
```

I invoke this rake target and other logic in a ruby file, like this:

```
Rake.application.init
Rake.application.load_rakefile
Rake.application['local:headless'].reenable
Rake.application['local:headless'].invoke
> ruby dom_audit_parser.rb
(this runs as expected)
```

Everything above executes fine, my tests run and i get my results.

HOWEVER, I'd like to execute the ruby script through PHP, so i have the following code to 'exec' the command:

```
$cmd = 'cd <_projectdirectory_snipped_>; ruby dom_audit_parser.rb';
exec($cmd, $results);
```

PROBLEM: It returns no examples run, as if it cannot find them.

BUT, I can run the same command (copied from the exec cmd in php) directly in the terminal with all examples being run. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?

The command below shows that the file is being specified and found, no examples are skipped, but nothing is found.

**output from PHP 'exec' command**

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -S rspec dom_audit_webdriver_spec.rb -f documentation --color Run
options: include {:local=>true} Finished in 0.00017 seconds 0 examples, 0 failures
```

**output from running the ruby command directly in a terminal**

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -S rspec dom_audit_webdriver_spec.rb -f documentation --color
Run options: include {:local=>true}    
Inspect the webpage to scrape the DOM object
-- [LOCAL] Starting firefox :
[2013-10-09 16:19:10 -0400] Logging in
[2013-10-09 16:19:10 -0400] Opening webpage
..... SNIP
-- [LOCAL] quit firefox
  should find the dom object for the html node    
Finished in 2 minutes 0.2 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Note that I've tried adding the code to a spec directory and not specifiying the file directly. It finds the file the 'rspec spec' way, but the same issue is observed.

```
├── config.yaml
├── dom_audit_parser.rb
├── dom_audit_portal.php
├── dom_audit_webdriver.rb
├── Rakefile
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is happening if You execute exactly the same command directly in shell?

Comment: added more detail to question

Comment: Is PHP processes run by the same user as Ruby is when You are running same command in shell ?

Comment: Thank you, that was the culprit.

Comment: That's quite a common mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

vim /etc/sudoers
add:

```
"www-data        ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL"
```

From PHP:

```
exec("sudo xyz");
```